# pull instead of push for core.async channels?

Tags: clojure, core.async

I am wondering why data from a core.async channel is retrieved by a pull mechanism in a endless loop. For example:

```
user=> (def c (chan 1))
#'user/c

user=> (go-loop []
         (let [x (<! c)]
           (println "Got a value in this loop:" x))
         (recur))

#<ManyToManyChannel clojure.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel@30df0e27>
```

ref: https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core.async/go-loop#example-542c88e3e4b05f4d257a297b

Why isn't there a push mechanism which I could hook onto? Or why isn't such a loop some implementation detail of core.async subscriber?
I think having a mechanism running endlessly is very cpu consuming. Is this not the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docstring for `core.async/go` says:

> Asynchronously executes the body, returning immediately to the
>   calling thread. Additionally, any visible calls to ! and alt!/alts!
>   channel operations within the body will block (if necessary) by
>   'parking' the calling thread rather than tying up an OS thread (or
>   the only JS thread when in ClojureScript). Upon completion of the
>   operation, the body will be resumed.
>    Returns a channel which will receive the result of the body when
>   completed

If `go` didn't park when it was waiting for new messages on the queue, then looping would indeed be very wasteful on the CPU. However, when the go loop reaches `<!` it will park the thread and will only resume when a value is available to take from the queue.

Comment: "Clojure for the brave and true" has a wonderful chapter on [master concurrent processes with core.async](http://www.braveclojure.com/core-async/) that explains this in detail.